# Next buttons userform Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an admin sheet that has a column containing a list of True and False. I am building a userform UI so users can click next (for now - building previous button after making next work), the userform will show the next False item in admin sheet and its corresponding data in Sheet1 will be displayed in Textbox1.

Reason for this is the row id in admin sheet correlates with Sheet1. So if data in Sheet1 row(31) has something wrong, column(13) in Admin sheet row(31) will be False.

Code:

```
Dim n As Long
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row

n = 7
With Worksheets("Admin")
    For i = n To LR
        If .Cells(i, 13).Value = "False" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Me.TextBox1 = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                Exit For
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End With
n = i + 1

End Sub
```

This successfully goes to the next False item and displays it correctly in Textbox1. However, it does not iterate to the next one..

Whatever logic we use to set up Next, I am going to assume Previous will be the same?

Thanks guys.

Comment: You have to "remember" the value of i each time you find a "False", then next time the user presses Next, start your loop at that value+1   You can use a Global variable to store the value.

Comment: Okay - so I initialised the data to start at first row. And had this code running and adding n + 1 by the end. Same logic for previous I presume? What happens when you reach the end in both sides?

Comment: When you reach the end you inform the user.

Comment: `n = 7`  << here you're resetting your global every call.  Try changing that to `If n=0 then n=7`

Comment: Okay - Brilliant. How would I go about doing the Previous button? I cant use the same logic. Because merely the statement For i = n to LR means auto increment by +1, but I want to do the opposite... Any ideas?

Comment: `For i = n to 7 Step -1`

Comment: Awesome -  I didn't know you can step backwards in a For Loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub cmdNext_Click()
    FindRow True
End Sub

Sub cmdPrev_Click()
    FindRow False
End Sub


Private Sub FindRow(bForward As Boolean)
    Const RW_START As Long = 7

    Dim LR As Long, t As Long, dir As Long, i As Long
    LR = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'going forwards, or back?
    If bForward Then
        n = IIf(n = 0, RW_START, n + 1) '<< Start at top
        t = LR                          '<< towards here
        dir = 1                         '<< increasing
    Else
        n = IIf(n = 0, LR, n - 1)       '<< Start at bottom
        t = RW_START                    '<< towards here
        dir = -1                        '<< decreasing
    End If

    For i = n To t Step dir
        If Worksheets("Admin").Cells(i, 13).Value = "False" Then
            Me.TextBox1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            n = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```